# Ruby- Adding/subtracting elements from one array with another array

Tags: ruby, arrays, matrix, addition, subtraction

I do this:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]  
b = [2,3,4,5]  
c = b - a  
put c
```

I get this
answer -> `[1]`
I want this answer -> `[1,1,1,1]` (like matrix addition/subtraction)

I tried this:

```
c.each {|e| c[e] = b[e] - a[e]}
```

but I get this answer: `[1,0,0,0]`

Can someone give me a correct way to do this?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could use [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260):

```
a.zip(b).map { |x, y| y - x }
# => [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

There is also a [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/classes/Matrix.html) class:

```
require "matrix"

a = Matrix[[1, 2, 3, 4]]
b = Matrix[[2, 3, 4, 5]]
c = b - a
# => Matrix[[1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I converted everything to a matrix.  One more question.  What would I use to automate constructing and then filling a matrix?  I used array1 = Array.new(hi) {|e| e = 0} to construct and fill a user defined array with 0's.  Is there a similar command for matrices?  Thanks again!

Comment: @subyman `Matrix.build` might be what you're looking for. Check the [doc for mor info](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/classes/Matrix.html#M001112). There are a number of methods though.

Comment: @sawa Thanks, but I'm trying to apply this to matrices now.

Comment: @Andy I will play around with those.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: For the record, the answer to my question is: a = Matrix.build(1,4) {0} which gives [[0,0,0,0]]

Comment: Well, I just figured out matrices are immutable in ruby, so I have to scratch that plan.  I will just use the array operation with zip.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `each_with_index` and `map`.

```
 c = b.each_with_index.map { |n,i| n - a[i] }
 # => [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I keep forgetting what was added in 1.9.